# Drag & Drop file upload on RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am looking for a solution for file uploading via Drag and Drop feature. I am using JSF 1.2 with JBoss 5.0.
If the solution is there on any RichFaces version then please share.

Thanks

Comment: So why don't you open Richfaces documentation?

Comment: Aquillo, I am unable to find any feature there. Just looking for someone has already developed it..

Comment: With 'Drag & Drop' you mean dragging them from a local folder, say `My Documents` into the website?

Comment: Yes drag file(s) from local folder and drop into the web page.

Comment: is there any developed solution specifically for jsf 1.2 (Version independent)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new in `richfaces`. Richfaces provides its Showcase with source for how to do it.
checkout richfaces Showcase, [Here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky).

**html file :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<ui:composition>

    <h:outputStylesheet>
        .top {
        vertical-align: top;
        }

        .info {
        height: 202px;
        overflow: auto;
        }
    </h:outputStylesheet>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="top,top">
            <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
                ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5">
                <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" />
            </rich:fileUpload>
            <h:panelGroup id="info" layout="block">
                <rich:panel bodyClass="info">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Uploaded Files Info" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="No files currently uploaded" rendered="#{fileUploadBean.size==0}" />
                    <rich:dataGrid columns="1" value="#{fileUploadBean.files}" var="file" rowKeyVar="row">
                        <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" createContent="#{fileUploadBean.paint}"
                                    value="#{row}" style="width:100px; height:100px;" cacheable="false">
                                    <f:param value="#{fileUploadBean.timeStamp}" name="time" />
                                </a4j:mediaOutput>
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                    <h:outputText value="File Name:" />
                                    <h:outputText value="#{file.name}" />
                                    <h:outputText value="File Length(bytes):" />
                                    <h:outputText value="#{file.length}" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </rich:panel>
                    </rich:dataGrid>
                </rich:panel>
                <br />
                <a4j:commandButton action="#{fileUploadBean.clearUploadData}" render="info, upload" value="Clear Uploaded Data"
                    rendered="#{fileUploadBean.size>0}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

**Java File:**

```
package org.richfaces.demo.fileupload;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.richfaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.richfaces.model.UploadedFile;

/**
 * @author Ilya Shaikovsky
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadBean implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<UploadedImage> files = new ArrayList<UploadedImage>();

    public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
        stream.write(getFiles().get((Integer) object).getData());
        stream.close();
    }

    public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
        UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
        UploadedImage file = new UploadedImage();
        file.setLength(item.getData().length);
        file.setName(item.getName());
        file.setData(item.getData());
        files.add(file);
    }

    public String clearUploadData() {
        files.clear();
        return null;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        if (getFiles().size() > 0) {
            return getFiles().size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public ArrayList<UploadedImage> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(ArrayList<UploadedImage> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

Comment: jubinPatel, I am asking for a drag & drop component. The above example is only a file upload component which is more like a browse button example. Well, i have implemented the drag & drop long ago and now its in production.

Answer (score 0):

I provide the code of the class **UploadedImage** which is in **the same package** than the class **FileUploadBean**.
[link for getting the code of the class UploadedImage](https://github.com/richfaces4/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/richfaces/demo/fileupload/UploadedImage.java)

```
package org.richfaces.demo.fileupload;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UploadedImage implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String mime;
    private long length;
    private byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        int extDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (extDot > 0) {
            String extension = name.substring(extDot + 1);
            if ("bmp".equals(extension)) {
                mime = "image/bmp";
            } else if ("jpg".equals(extension)) {
                mime = "image/jpeg";
            } else if ("gif".equals(extension)) {
                mime = "image/gif";
            } else if ("png".equals(extension)) {
                mime = "image/png";
            } else {
                mime = "image/unknown";
            }
        }
    }

    public long getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(long length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getMime() {
        return mime;
    }
}
```

I hope I help the people who want use the "rich:fileUpload" component